# Automated equivalents of Potentiometers

Tags: digital-logic, programming, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I am currently working on a project to create an amplifier which can use both physical and digital inputs to change the resistance of a potentiometer.

Is this possible without using sliders?

I know this sounds like a pretty odd question but I'm not sure how else I could do it as all the Pots I've found are either Digital or Analogue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You mean motorized pots?

Answer (score 2):

Motorized potentiometers are a thing, although they are not used much on new equipment.

Another option is to use an encoder to detect knob rotation and use that to update a digital pot.

Comment: Hi Jasen, thank you for your help I'll look into these things tomorrow :D

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Ben.

Maybe what you are looking for is a programmable gain amplifier (PGA) like [this one](https://circuitsstream.blogspot.com/2013/05/programmable-gain-amplifier-circuit.html) (sorry the schematic looks quite old). [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable-gain_amplifier) on programmable gain amplifiers gives also two links to integrated circuits. There is also a discussion on PGA [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209390/programmable-gain-instrumentation-amplifier-with-r-2r-ladder-and-analog-multiple).

The gain depends on a binary word that could be generated:

- either directly by your digital system
- or from a physical slider and an analog to digital converter (ADC)

The choice between the two input is up to you.

Comment: Hi Charles, This sounds like a pretty neat Idea I'll have a look at this when i research Jasen's comment above. Thanks again Ben